# How can I exclude a field from the schema when generating schemas in Jackon?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, jackson-modules

I'm using Jackson's `JsonSchemaGenerator` to generate schemas for my beans. One of these beans have a getter that I would like to exclude from the schema generation (or alternatively, mark is as an "object" - not any).

How would I go about generating a schema but forcing the `address` property to be either excluded or any object?

```
public static class Person {

    private final String firstName;

    private final String lastName;

    private final Address address;

    public Person(
            @JsonProperty("first_name") String firstName,
            @JsonProperty("last_name") String lastName,
            @JsonProperty("address") Address address) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("address")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

I haven't found a way to achieve this using Jackson.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood what you want to achieve but maybe it can be accomplished with `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: What do you mean by "or any object"?

Comment: If I did use the JsonIgnore, it would be excluded entirely from serialization. Ideally I just don't want a schema for the address field and it doesn't need to be

`"address" : { "type" : "any" }`

It should simply be `"address" : {}`

Comment: By design, this (slightly outdated) schema generator aims at reflecting what Jackson returns. Your best options are probably manipulating the generated schema afterwards or use a different generator library (I'm biased here as maintainer of one such alternative).